# Pressing a key twice quickly to trigger a function in AutoHotKey

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I want to bind 'jj' to Esc using AutoHotkey in my Rstudio application. Is there any way we can map 'jj' to trigger Escape in a selected windows application?

Comment: Do you want to double click the key `j` to send `esc`?

Comment: Yes, like we can map in Vim. Double press j triggers Esc.

Comment: What have you tried already on your side? If you haven't already checked in out, then I recommend reading the documentation for [`ifWinActive`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm) and [`Hotstrings`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm). Those two together should help you create a solution.

Comment: The issue becomes what do you want to happen when you press `j` normally (i.e. a single time)? Do you want it to wait indefinitely for another keystroke and then if a non-`j` is pressed retroactively send the original `j`. Or do you want it to function differently than this?

Comment: Have you attempted this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, that worked.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe rstudio.exe

l::
 {
   count++
   settimer, actions, 150
 }
return

actions:
 {
  if (count = 1)
    {
      Send j
    }
   else if (count = 2)
    {
      Send {Esc}
    }
 count := 0
 }
return
```

Comment: Can you mark the answer as accepted so the question is closed, please?